# Replacing a property value in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

If I have a JSON structure that looks something like this:

```
var user = {
    map: {
        width: 785,
        height: 791
    },
    image: {
        name: "image.png",
        size: {width:32}
    },
    properties:[{
        firstName: "Bob",
        lastName: "Jones",
    }]
};
```

How would I change (after creation) the value of the `firstName` property to "Jane"?

I am fairly new to JSON, and I'm just trying to figure out how to make this one change for now.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a function, you should be able to change it with user.properties[0].firstName = "Jane".

Comment: Instead of changing the title to indicate "Resolved", the way to close a question on StackOverflow is to click the checkmark to the left of one of the answers you received to designate that as your "Accepted" answer. :o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, one reason for your confusion might be that this is not JSON at all. JSON is a text format used for serialising objects. This is just a literal object in Javascript.

To change the `firstName` property, you would access the first item in the `properties` array in the `user` object:

```
user.properties[0].firstName = "Jane";
```

Comment: +1 for the JSON clarification. I've grown tired of fighting that battle!

Answer (score 4):

As long as the `user` variable is in scope:

```
user.properties[0].firstName = "Jane";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var changeName = function(obj, newName) {
   obj.properties[0].firstName = newName;
   return obj;
}
```

Comment: i think you mean `return obj;`

Comment: @Guffa: Yes, but it appears as though it was changed by someone other than OP.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question and the solutions to it but my script still didn't work.
I found the solution and I figured I should post this here, it might save some people a little research.

My JSON result had some integers in it and it required the parseInt() function.

Taking the above example you probably have to do something like this.

```
user.map.width = parseInt(somevariable);
```

Since javascript is loosely typed I never really worry about it, but in this case it's necessary.