# Change JSON File with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Does changing a JSON file with JS acutally affect the JSON file or does it only change the JSON file in temp memory?

#### Code

```
user.properties[0].firstName = "Jane";
```

This is from [Replacing a property value in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418814/replacing-a-property-value-in-json).

### Edit

I am not using a server to develop my website, but will be using one when I post it.

Comment: Unless you're writing the object back to disk it only affects the copy stored in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would only affect the json in memory, you would then need to write the changes back to the filesystem for it to update the file contents.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Post the changes back to the server and use whatever server side language you running to write the contents.

Comment: What if I am not using a server to design my website?

Comment: How are you hosting it then ? What is you dev setup?

Comment: I am hosting it on a local server.

Comment: `What if I am not using a server`... `I am hosting it on a local server`.... which one is it?

Comment: I am developing my website on my personal computer as I don't have access to the server right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163591/discussion-between-ds-secret-and-btl).

Comment: Are you there? Could you please answer my question?

Comment: That really doesn't change anything. Are you running a local webserver or doing this all in notepad? Either way you'll need to send modified content to the "server" and then write the file.

Comment: Is there a way I could simulate the server on my computer.

Comment: I have a Dell Inspiron desktop.