# How to replacing properties of an json object with new

Tags: javascript

This object generates depends on custom fields that come from the backend.
Need a function that replaces some fields on a new and other delete or not include in submit object

```
 {
    "originating_office": {
      "code": "string", **replace on "value": "string",**
      "description": "string" **replace on "label": "string"**
    },
    "petty_cash_account": {
      "number": "string", **replace on "value": "string",**
      "name": "SOME DATA", **replace on "value": "string",**
      "gls_account": "SOME DATA-HERE", **just add new filed**
      "currency": "SOME", **just add new filed**
      "origination_office_of": "" **just add new filed**
    },
    "item": "simple string",
    "amount": "0.7",
    "spending_unit": {
      "indexno": "08805544", **save**
      "display_name": "Mark Twen", **delete**
      "position_title": null, **delete**
      "org_unit_name": "", **delete**
      "extension": null, **delete**
      "country": "Italy", **delete**
      "duty_station": "2250", **delete**
      "email": "user@example.com", **save**
      "last_name": "Some", **save**
      "first_name": "Data", **save**
      "username": "some.data", **delete**
      "text": "Some DATA" **save**
    },
  }
```

But can't imagine what to do forward

```
const replaceDataByNew = (obj) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty('originating_office')) {
      console.log("originating_office");
      
    }
    if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty('cash_collected')) {
      console.log("cash_collected");
    }
  }
};

replaceDataByNew(data);
```

I tried to refactor this next approach: [Replacing a property value in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418814/replacing-a-property-value-in-json), but unfortunately. I will appreciate it if you help me

Comment: When things depend, you need to write conditions or use a switch.

Comment: Maybe try something along these lines: https://ajv.js.org/guide/getting-started.html?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. What is the relationship between the input and the output?

Comment: The normalization being done in the other questions is nothing like what you seem to want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changes you want are very specific, where you know each field you want to change, you can modify each property. If the object above is in variable x

```
let x = {
  originating_office: { code: "string", description: "string" },
  petty_cash_account: {
    number: "string",
 and so on
```

You can simply do this.

```
//This modifies the value of code to "A new string"
x.originating_office.code = "A new string";    
//This deletes the display_name property on the spending unit property
delete x.spending_unit.display_name;
//You can also reference properties using this format
delete x["spending_unit"]["display_name"];
//Javascript is dynamic, you add a new property like this.
x.petty_cash_account.currency = "USD";
```

If you want to loop though all the properties of an object use Object.values

```
Object.values(x).forEach((key,val)=>console.log(key,val))
```